# How to click on an element of a website with javascript bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

what i want to do is to click on this icons (there are like 16 per website, one by one, click the first, go to the next available, etc....

To understanding... [image: Image 1]

And sometimes it has this other eye icon: (it changes the code a bit)
[image: Image 2]

I know we could do it from the console, but for comfort i would prefer to do this from the bookmarks (adding the code to a bookmark, then click it when i need it)
So, what i know (thanks to @Sphinx) is that we have to write in a **bookmarklet**`javascript:$("span.icon.icon_eye").click()` but the **main problem** is that when i click it, it clicks the first icon eye, and i need to click first the 1st eye icon, then the second, then the third, etc...

Comment: sorry but didn't get any of what you're saying

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Ok i will write it better (i hope :D) I need to click on the eye icon you see in the first page is selected, but with a Bookmarklet

Comment: not sure whatyou need, but you can try`$('span.icon.icon_eye').on('click', function(){console.log('You clicked', $(this).html())});$('span.icon.icon_eye').click()` if that website uses JQuery

Comment: @GeorgeBailey just in case, a bookmarklet is a browser bookmark for a URL using the 'javascript:' protocol. The 'javascript:' prefix is followed by a snippet of JavaScript code. When invoked, instead of navigating to a new page, the script is executed within the context of the current page. (Definition by StackOverFlow)

Comment: @Sphinx ok so what you gave me works fine, except it clicks always the first icon_eye (all eye icons are called the same, so how could we do to click the first, then the second, etc.
Btw, i wasn't much clear? if so i will try to explain better the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, below codes should be what you need.

1. [bind](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `click` event for all `span.icon_eye`.
2. Click [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `<span class="icon icon_eys">` second by second ([setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)).

```js
function clickSomething() {
  $('span.icon.icon_eye').on('click', function(){console.log('You clicked', $(this).html())});
  $('span.icon.icon_eye').each(function(index){setTimeout(()=>{$(this).click()}, index*1000);});
}

setTimeout(clickSomething, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="icon icon_eye">A</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">B</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">C</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">D</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">E</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">F</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much man, it was exactly what i needed.
But you mind explaining me a bit as what you did there? So i understand better to learn more, as i am new in javascript ?

I understood until this part: $('span.icon.icon_eye').on('click', function(){console.log('You clicked'... Then with "this" I am not sure to what are you referencing? The class or the address maybe? well please explain me the rest as i got lost there.

And the code snippet <span class="icon icon_eye">C</span> it was just so i saw the example or something like that? sorry my ignorance and thanks for your time

Comment: for **this** keyword, you can check [this url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to study what it is. At above snippet, **this** is the object which is clicked. Also I edited my answer then added some related document URL.

Comment: last question... what about this part? each(function(index){setTimeout(()=>{$(this).click()}, index*1000);});

"each" I believe it's kind of a For that executes the function index, which is a delay of 1000ms, but if it doesn't sums +1 like in the regular for (i mean there is no counter) why it keeps doing it?

Thanks for all! <3

Comment: `.each()` is the method provided by JQuery. check this url [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
var currentBookmark = $($('.icon_eye').get(0));
var bookmarkClicker = function() {
  console.log('you clicked bookmark at ' + currentBookmark.text());
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentBookmark = currentBookmark.next('.icon_eye');
    if (currentBookmark) {
      currentBookmark.on('click', bookmarkClicker);
      currentBookmark.click();
    }
  }, 500);
};
currentBookmark.on('click', bookmarkClicker);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="icon icon_eye">A</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">B</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">C</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">D</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">E</span>
<span class="icon icon_eye">F</span>
</div>
```